# Sql Connection fails when using Integrated Security on IIS applications

Tags: sql-server, authentication, iis, connection-string

In my web application on IIS 7.0, I want to make a connection to Sql Database Server for which my user is granted for Windows Authentication. (Integrated Security=SSPI)

Login fails for user 'DOMAIN\COMPUTER_NAME$', however I still can connect to database over connect window of Sql Server Management Studio (with DOMAIN\USER_NAME).

How can I connect to Sql Server over my web application?

Comment: See this...http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998320.aspx#paght000015%5Fsqlserver

Comment: SSMS is a single hop (local pc -> Database). NTLM or Kerberos can do single hops. Connecting via the web app is a double hop (local pc -> Web Server -> Database). You cannot do a double hop without Kerberos Delegation enabled. This is fairly complicated but is worth the effort if you can get it configured correctly.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I've found the solution.

On IIS, open Application Pool settings.

For Identity option, choose "Custom Account".

Enter your username (DOMAIN\USERNAME) and password.

It's done.

Comment: where is this application pool?

Comment: Thank you!!!! After several hours of struggling with this - this did it! So many other issues had resolutions that called for changing the identity to "ApplicationPoolIdentity", so that is what it was set as. Thanks again!

Comment: @VasilValchev it is in IIS Under the Server Name

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I had to assign the application pool accounts in SQL Server the db_owner role. I felt that was too much permission but it is the only thing that worked. my book said to give it db_datareader and db_datawriter roles but that did not work.

I'm using SQL Server with Windows Authentication, Windows 7 Home Premium with IIS all on the same machine.

Perhaps someone else will search this issue and find my answer useful.